# MixPre-3 mixer input signal isn't working on Ubuntu 20.04 but does on 18.04. How do I fix this?

Tags: sound, usb

I've got MixPre-3 mixer. When I have a microphone attached to it and the 2 usb cords attached to the mixer and laptop in Ubuntu 18.04 I see the Mixer in both the input and output settings. If I select the input setting when the microphone is attached and having audacity running in Ubuntu 18.04 I can record. In Ubuntu 20.04 no signal is present (this is what I have found out on my laptop which I have both Ubuntu 20.04 and Ubuntu 18.04 installed on it). How do get Ubuntu to receive the signal of the mixer with the microphone attached?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MixPre-D USB audio interface shows up as "Output Device," not "Input Device" in Lubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1281404/mixpre-d-usb-audio-interface-shows-up-as-output-device-not-input-device-in)

Comment: Yes I saw that post. In his post he can't see his MixPre-D as an input device. I can see my MixPre-3 as both input and as output devices within Ubuntu 20.04 but when I select it as input and try to record with a  microphone attached to the MixPre-3 no signal is displayed on the  "input level" in the sound settings display. In Ubuntu 18.04 a signal is recorded in the sound settings.